# retrieving text input from popup in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I copied some code that makes a popup appear on screen to my program and the popup has a textbox. I want to pass the text in there to a function as a parameter and im having some trouble doing so. the .text property isnt an option since the popup is declared in a class method and i dont know how to define a popup that acts in the same way as an instance inside of my main app class.
main program:

```py
import os
import cryptography
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet


def gen_key():
    key = Fernet.generate_key()
    with open("new_key", "w") as f:
        f.write("SAVE THIS KEY TO DECRYPT DATA\nDO NO SHARE THIS KEY WITH ANYONE\n==============================================\n")
        f.write(key.decode("ASCII"))
    return key


#secret_key = gen_key()

def encrypt(filename, key):
    """
    Given a filename (str) and key (bytes), it encrypts the file and write it
    """
    f = Fernet(key)
    with open(filename, "rb") as file:
        # read all file data
        file_data = file.read()
    # encrypt data
    encrypted_data = f.encrypt(file_data)
    # write the encrypted file
    with open(filename, "wb") as file:
        file.write(encrypted_data)


def decrypt(filename, key):
    """
    Given a filename (str) and key (bytes), it decrypts the file and write it
    """
    #key = input("enter key: ")
    f = Fernet(key)
    with open(filename, "rb") as file:
        # read the encrypted data
        encrypted_data = file.read()
    # decrypt data
    decrypted_data = f.decrypt(encrypted_data)
    # write the original file
    with open(filename, "wb") as file:
        file.write(decrypted_data)


def main(directory, option, secret_key):

    # assign directory
    # directory = input("Enter path pls: ") | taken as parameter
    # option = input("(E)ncryption or (D)ecryption?: ")  | taken as parameter
    # iterate over files that directory
    if option.lower() == "e":
        #secret_key = input("Enter key to encrypt with: ")
        for filename in os.listdir(directory):
            f = os.path.join(directory, filename)
            if os.path.isfile(f): # checking if it is a file
                encrypt(f, secret_key)
    elif option.lower() == "d":
        #secret_key = input("Enter key to decrypt with: ")
        for filename in os.listdir(directory):
            f = os.path.join(directory, filename)
            if os.path.isfile(f): # checking if it is a file
                decrypt(f, secret_key)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

kivy file

```py
import fix_proj
import kivy
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup


class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2

        self.gen_key = Button(text="Generate Key: ",
                              font_size=30, on_press=self.gen_key_press)
        self.key_output = TextInput()

        self.add_widget(self.gen_key)
        self.add_widget(self.key_output)

        self.encrypt = Button(text="Encrypt Directory: ",
                              font_size=30, on_press=self.encrypt_popup_key)
        self.encrypted_dir = TextInput()
        self.add_widget(self.encrypt)
        self.add_widget(self.encrypted_dir)

        self.decrypt = Button(text="Decrypt Directory: ", font_size=30, on_press = self.decrypt_popup_key)
        self.decrypted_dir = TextInput()
        self.add_widget(self.decrypt)
        self.add_widget(self.decrypted_dir)

    def gen_key_press(self, event):
        self.key_output.text = fix_proj.gen_key()

    def encrypt_popup_key(self, event):
        layout = GridLayout(cols = 1, padding = 10)
  
        key_input = TextInput(text = "")
        closeButton = Button(text = "Apply")
  
        layout.add_widget(key_input)
        layout.add_widget(closeButton)       
  
        # Instantiate the modal popup and display
        popup = Popup(title ='Enter key:',
                      content = layout,
                      size_hint =(None, None), size =(200, 200))  
        popup.open()   
  
        # Attach close button press with popup.dismiss action
        closeButton.bind(on_press = self.enc_dir_input)
        #popup.dismiss()

    def decrypt_popup_key(self, event):
        layout = GridLayout(cols = 1, padding = 10)
  
        key_input = TextInput(text = "")
        closeButton = Button(text = "Apply")
  
        layout.add_widget(key_input)
        layout.add_widget(closeButton)       
  
        # Instantiate the modal popup and display
        popup = Popup(title ='Enter key:',
                      content = layout,
                      size_hint =(None, None), size =(200, 200))  
        popup.open()   
  
        # Attach close button press with popup.dismiss action
        closeButton.bind(on_press = self.dec_dir_input)
        #popup.dismiss()

    # TODO bind it to its respective button and pass params accordingly
    def enc_dir_input(self, dir):
        fix_proj.main(self.encrypted_dir.text, 'e', self.encrypt_popup_key.key_input.text)

    # TODO bind it to its respective button and pass params accordingly
    def dec_dir_input(self, dir):
        fix_proj.main(self.decrypted_dir.text, 'd', self.decrypt_popup_key.key_input.text)


class Encryptor(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Encryptor().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bellow is the implementation for your method `enc_dir_input`. Similar applies to other.

First pass the `key_input.text` through `closeButton.on_press`.

```py
closeButton.bind(on_press = lambda *args : self.enc_dir_input(key_input.text))
```

Now access this text in the desired method,

```py
    def enc_dir_input(self, text):
        fix_proj.main(self.encrypted_dir.text, 'e', text)
```